# Reading Wordpress Database Data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not entirely sure what to call this, and I had a tough time searching for helpful results.

I have a wordpress plugin for a contact form that inputs the data into the database like this.

```
    a:37:{i:0;a:8:{s:2:"id";s:2:"20";s:4:"slug";s:11:"enfant-kind";
s:4:"name";s:13:"options_other";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:2:"21";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}}
```

This is only part of it and it's pretty long. I'm wondering how I can read this using PHP to break apart the form fields and inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

That should turn that string into a object.

$data = unserialize($raw_data_from_db);

For anecdotal info, a:37 means an array thats 37 elements long, i:0 is for integer 0, s:'s are strings and their size.  There's two more letters but as long as you are using serialize and unserialize, you should be good to go.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you! Will accept as soon as it lets me. Figured it had to be something simple, just didn't know what to search for.

Comment: It's one of those things where the first time you see it, the response is "WTF is that?"

Comment: I would actually recommend using `maybe_unserialize()` which is part of the WordPress Codex. Not everything in the db is serialized, so this function will conditionally unserialize it as needed: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize